# Maximizing entropy

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, entropy

Let $v_1<\cdots<v_n$ and $\mu\in(v_1,v_n)$ be real numbers. Consider set
$$X=\left\{(p_1,\ldots,p_n)\in[0,1]^n\ |\ \sum_{i=1}^np_i=1,\ \sum_{i=1}^np_iv_i=\mu\right\},$$
which is convex (easy) and [compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3136655/155134). Consider entropy 
$$H:X\to\mathbb R,\ H(p_1,\ldots,p_n)=-\sum_{j=1}^np_j\log_2p_j,$$
and let us look for maximum. $H$ is strictly concave continuous function on compact convex set, therefore there is unique $x^*\in X$ such that $H(x^*)=\max\{H(x)\,|\,x\in X\}.$ Construct Langrangian as
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}(p_1,\ldots,p_n;\lambda_1,\lambda_2)&=-\sum_{j=1}^np_j\log_2p_j+\lambda_1\left(1-\sum_{j=1}^np_j\right)+\lambda_2\left(\mu-\sum_{j=1}^np_jv_j\right)= \\
&=\lambda_1+\lambda_2\mu-\sum_{j=1}^np_j\left(\lambda_1+\lambda_2v_j+\log_2p_j\right),
\end{align*}
from which I received system of $n+2$ equations
$$p_j=2^{-\lambda_1-\lambda_2v_j}/e,\quad\sum_{k=1}^np_k=1,\quad\sum_{k=1}^np_kv_k=\mu.$$

Now, I would like to provide a reason that the previous system has a solution. Moreover, if the solution were unique, I would not need to bother with the boundary points. But is there any feasible way how to show that? <del>(I want to avoid second partial derivative test.)</del>

At first, I thought the maximum cannot be achieved on a boundary, but $[-1,0]\to\mathbb R,x\mapsto -x^2$ provides a counterexample.

Comment: Look at Weierstrass' Theorem and at strict convexity. Uniqueness does not mean that the solution cannot be on the boundary.

Comment: @LinAlg Is that just a general comment? Because, I'm sorry, but is it useful?

Comment: It answers some of your question. "I would like to provide a reason that the previous system has a solution" is answered by Weierstrass' theorem, and "if the solution were unique" is answered by strict convexity. Overall, the KKT conditions should help you find the solution.

Comment: @LinAlg Still I feel like I miss something. If the maximum is attained on the boundary, then the system does not have a solution, so how does [Weierstrass' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Generalization_to_metric_and_topological_spaces) work here?

Comment: Also would you also need to show that the Lagrangian solution, when it does exist, is actually the maximum point, and that it is unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plug $p_j=2^{-\lambda_1-\lambda_2v_j}/e$ into the last two equations
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=1}^np_k=1\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \sum_{k=1}^n2^{-\lambda_1-\lambda_2v_k}/e=1\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \sum_{k=1}^n2^{-\lambda_2v_k}=e2^{\lambda_1} \\
&\sum_{k=1}^np_kv_k=\mu\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \sum_{k=1}^nv_k2^{-\lambda_1-\lambda_2v_k}/e=\mu\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \sum_{k=1}^nv_k2^{-\lambda_2v_k}=e\mu2^{\lambda_1} \\
&\Longrightarrow\ \ \sum_{k=1}^nv_k2^{-\lambda_2v_k}=\mu\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-\lambda_2v_k}\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \sum_{k=1}^n(v_k-\mu)2^{-\lambda_2v_k}=0
\end{align*}
and the last equation has a [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3145848/155134).

Second partial derivative test says it would be a maximum as $p_j>0.$ (In fact, the test is quite pleasant since the Hessian is a diagonal matrix.) The obtained solution is unique from strict concavity. (Hence, there is no maximum on the boundary.)